# Ms Access Duplicate entry check for date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

I am trying to write a VBA code on msaccess to validate the data entries to avoid duplicates on a fault log database. It works for the stLinkCriteria which is a string datatype (short text) but not for stDCriteria which is a date data type... it keeps throwing an error "type mismatch" or "datatype mismatch" on this line

```
stDCriteria = "[datelogged] = #" & DateTime & "#"
```

The stDCriteria is showing 12:00:00am when I hover my mouse on the code

Although the data type for datelogged is Date/Time in the database...

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
Dim NewTerminal As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
Dim DateTime As Date
Dim stDCriteria As Date

NewTerminal = Me.cboTerID.Value
DateTime = Me.txtDateLogged.Value
stLinkCriteria = "[serialptrid] = " & NewTerminal & ""
stDCriteria = "[datelogged] = #" & DateTime & "#"
If Me.SerialptrID = DLookup("[serialptrid]", "Fault_Log", stLinkCriteria) Then
If Me.DateLogged = DLookup("[datelogged]", "Fault_Log", stDCriteria) Then
 MsgBox "This terminal " & NewTerminal & ", " & DateTime & ", has already been entered in this database." _
        & vbCr & vbCr & "Please check terminal selected", vbInformation, "Duplicate information"
        Me.Undo
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This code attempts to assign a string value to `stDCriteria`:

```
stDCriteria = "[datelogged] = #" & DateTime & "#"
```

So you must declare that variable as String instead of Date.

```
Dim stDCriteria As String
```

Also you can apply a *yyyy-m-d* format to your `DateTime` value.  That format avoids confusion about whether your date is *m/d/yyyy* or *d/m/yyyy* format.

```
stDCriteria = "[datelogged] = #" & Format(DateTime, "yyyy-m-d") & "#"
```